# Download files uploaded to the "static" folder - Django

Tags: python, html, django

I need the .wav file that is created in the "static" folder to be able to be downloaded via a link inserted via HTML or viewed via FileResponse.

I tried things like:

```
<a href="{% static 'files/{{ filename }}' %}">Download: {{ filename }} </a>
```

But this didn't work because it doesn't find the resource.

Comment: Generated media inside `media` folder. Right?

Comment: You have a security vulnerability. Uploaded files should be in the *media* folder not in the *static* folder. Better yet, files should be uploaded to a *CDN* and not in your project’s location.

Comment: If I wanted to create a section for each user who registers, who can upload their own files, do I have to use a CDN for security and privacy reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You try this code to solve your issue:

```
<a href="{% url 'download_wav' filename='your_wav_filename.wav' %}">Download .wav File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out make sure where to store your files.

After that You should add `download` attribute to your anchor tag. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp)

> The download attribute specifies that the target (the file specified in the href attribute) will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.
>
> The optional value of the download attribute will be the new name of the file after it is downloaded.

#### static files:

```html
<a href="{% static 'files/{{ filename }}' %}" download="{{ filename }}">Download: {{ filename }} </a>
```

#### media files:

```html
<a href="{{ dynamic_filename_url }}" download="{{ filename }}">Download: {{ filename }} </a>
```